# jQuery form submit not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

When I try to submit my form using enter button in IE7,IE9 or in FF everything is working fine. But in IE8 form submission not working.
I am using jQuery validation and form will submit after checking all validations.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 jQuery.fn.validated = function(callback){
        jQuery(this).each(function(){
           if (this.tagName == "FORM") {
            jQuery(this).submit(function(){
                if (ValidationErrors[jQuery(this).attr("id")].length == 0) 
                    callback();
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
};

 <form name="frmbrand" id="frmbrand" method='post'>
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
                <td width="30%" valign="top">Brand Name : </td>
                <td width="70%" valign="top"><input type="text" id="brandname" name="brandname"><span class="error">*</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Order : </td>
                <td valign="top"><input type="text" id="rank1" name="rank1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnsave1"  name="btnsave1" style="background:#ccc">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btncancel1" name="btncancel1" style="background:#ccc" ></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

<!-- language: lang-js -->
 jQuery("#frmbrand").validated(function(){})
```

Comment: can you try adding this tag to the document? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >

Comment: Not working in browser mode: IE8 and Document mode: IE8. Please help.

Comment: i'm not sure about this line -- can you try the tagname lowercase?  (this.tagName == "FORM")  .. also, the document isn't full, i can't say if something else is producing errors

Comment: no problem..i figured out the issue. IE=EmulateIE7 will fix IE in IE7 compatibility mode means in document mode: IE7 and my code is working prefect in IE7. Thnx Alex :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with IE8. Here is how I solve it:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnsave1"  name="btnsave1" 
style="background:#ccc"><!-- use button instead of submit-->

$("#btnsave1").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#frmbrand").submit();
});

$("#frmbrand").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do whatever you want here...
});
```